# SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: s2cor__Sage_INV_Trade_Document_Type__c. s2cor__Use_Company_Shipping__c

Tags: trigger, soql, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id, c#

I have a C# application that was meant to upload invoices to salesforce financials. All other functions of the application works fine except the uploading module. During the upload process, I have to create a new Transaction record using the ForceClient.CreateAsync() method. As seen below. Please note that I have created the Transaction object and set it's properties in a lengthy chunk of code.

```
SuccessResponse createTransResponse = await client.CreateAsync("s2cor__Sage_INV_Trade_Document__c", transactionObj);
```

When the application reaches the above line, it always crashes with the error below

**SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: s2cor__Sage_INV_Trade_Document_Type__c.s2cor__Use_Company_Shipping__c**

The transaction class itself looks line this;

```
public class Transaction
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public string s2cor__Reference__c { get; set; }
        public String s2cor__Account__c { get; set; }
        public String s2cor__Date__c { get; set; }
        public string s2cor__Trade_Document_Type__c = "a211v0000022YBpAAM"; 
        //public string s2cor__Net_Amount__c { get; set; }
        public string s2cor__Currency__c { get; set; }
        public string s2cor__Exchange_Rate__c { get; set; }
    }
```

After researching, I found that this new field **s2cor__Use_Company_Shipping__c** was added to Transaction_Type record in the 2019 release of salesforce. Some one said this error is related to a data trigger on the Transaction record. How do i stop it from occurring so that the transaction record can be created successfully? Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What package does the namespace `s2cor` correspond to? If you attempt to manually insert a record matching this structure through Workbench or Anonymous Apex, can you reproduce the error and get a stack track? It sounds like there's a trigger with a bug in it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like either something is querying the SObject in question (my guess being `s2cor__Sage_INV_Trade_Document__c`) and not also querying the field (which appears to actually be a relationship, `s2cor__Sage_INV_Trade_Document_Type__r.s2cor__Use_Company_Shipping__c`), or your class there isn't filling it out, with `s2cor__Sage_INV_Trade_Document_Type__c` only providing the id, not the associated complex class with an ID *and* s2cor__Use_Company_Shipping__c value.

```
public class Transaction
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public String Id { get; set; }
        public string s2cor__Reference__c { get; set; }
        public String s2cor__Account__c { get; set; }
        public String s2cor__Date__c { get; set; }
        public TradeDocumentType s2cor__Trade_Document_Type__c = new TradeDocumentType(); 
        //public string s2cor__Net_Amount__c { get; set; }
        public string s2cor__Currency__c { get; set; }
        public string s2cor__Exchange_Rate__c { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class TradeDocumentType
{
    public String Id "a211v0000022YBpAAM";
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public boolean s2cor__Use_Company_Shipping__c = { get; set; }; 
}
```

Comment: How do you suggest I fix it? I added the s2cor__Use_Company_Shipping__c field to my class but didn't get any positive result

Comment: Well, I can't see the rest of your code.  But if there's anything querying `s2cor__Sage_INV_Trade_Document_Type__c`, make sure that it's also querying `s2cor__Sage_INV_Trade_Document_Type__r.s2cor__Use_Company_Shipping__c` before proceeding.

For adding to your class there (I assume that's the C# side), based on the error, `s2cor__Trade_Document_Type__c` is no longer a simple String, but a complex class consisting of at least a String ID, and that new field.  I don't think this was a Salesforce update (these are all custom objects), but rather a Sage Update.

Comment: [Sage Update](https://developer.sage.com/api/financials/blog/2019/01/Jan2019-WhatsNewAPI.html)

Comment: That's the thing. The querying seems to happen within ForceClient.CreateAsync() method. So i have no way of editing the method to ensure that it also queries for s2cor__Sage_INV_Trade_Document_Type__r.s2cor__Use_Company_Shipping__c and there's very little documentation on how to create a transaction record

Comment: Hmm... Sounds like the `ForceClient` is doing something dynamic then based on your object.  I edited my answer to show how you could make that `s2cor__Sage_INV_Trade_Document_Type__c` complex... can you try that?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didnt work. I got this exeption **Cannot deserialize instance of reference from START_OBJECT value { or request may be missing a required field at [line:1, column:2]**

Comment: Ah, so a different error then... that's progress.  Sounds like you need your objects to correctly fill out the Sage models.  You might start with making sure the `Name` field is filled out on `TradeDocumentType` and that you have modeled all other new Sage objects/fields relevant to your transaction.

Comment: That didn't work